# IFiddlerWebTestPlugin not been picked up by fiddler

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, export, fiddler

Since the performance testing tools have been made available to VS2015 I thought I'd try out the webtest/loadtests and found that fiddler can already export directly the webtest format. The following article talks about custom plugins you can make for the export process but my version of Fiddler doesn't seem to pick them up.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2007/04/17/writing-fiddler-web-test-plugins/

Can anyone else get this working using the method described? For the examples purposes I took all logic out the plugin and still couldn't get it to display in the list of plugins. It does however lock the file when I open Fiddler? Does this feature still work? I added a post to the Telerik [forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/ifiddlerwebtestplugin-not-displaying) but they aren't particularly active so thought I'd try here as well.

Code below if anyone wants to try it:

Fiddler v4.6.3

```
using Fiddler.WebTesting;

namespace FiddlerPlugin
{
    public class FiddlerPluginTest : IFiddlerWebTestPlugin
    {
        public void PreWebTestSave(object sender, PreWebTestSaveEventArgs e)
        {
        //Test
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after de-compiling the VSWebTestExport.dll I found out about the **fiddler.debug.extensions.verbose** setting which allowed me to see more debugging information.

The problem was I hadn't included a Fiddler.RequiredVersion attribute in the assembly and the new folder it looks for custom WebTestPlugins is:

**%userprofile%\documents\Fiddler2\ImportExport\VSWebTestPlugins**

This folder will not exist by default.